# change color and width of some painted lines in an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, graphics, core-graphics

I'm painting some black lines in an `UIImageView` (in `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` methods) and there is one `UISlider` for modifying the width of these lines and some buttons for modifying the color of them.

How can that be done using CoreGraphics?

```
...
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theImage.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, theNewWidth);
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be trying to draw on a `UIImageView`. Instead, create your own subclass of `UIView` and override `-drawRect:`. When the events for those UI controls are fired, just call `-setNeedsDisplay` on your view class to ask it to be redrawn. Also, set some properties on your view class (e.g., `lineWidth`, `lineColor`).

In `-drawRect:`, use Core Graphics to redraw your view with the new values the user specified.

You can look at the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) for all the information you need about drawing with Core Graphics. Also, check out the [QuartzDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project from Apple. It demonstrates many, if not all, of Core Graphics's capabilities.

Comment: Thanks!! I've been having a look at QuartzDemo sample, and it always paints the lines from scratch with the new width (with CGContextMoveToPoint and CGContextAddLineToPoint). I cannot do that, cause the painted lines are painted by the user.

Comment: You are going to have to maintain the state of all the points the user is drawing. You can't simply adjust the property of some Core Graphics state and ask it to redraw everything. You have to redraw the entire view from scratch each time one of those settings is changed. To that end, you'll need to come up with a way to keep track of where the user taps and drags, etc.

Comment: Is there any other easier solution or framework for doing this (opengl, cocos2d...)?